# Rows as Columns and Vice Versa using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the data coming from an SQL in the below format as per screenshot 1 and I would need in the format as per the screenshot 2.

Please note the data that is in Screenshot 1 is dynamic. There can be any number of Rows and any number of columns. Also, I need this to be in a single SQL Query and not a PL/SQL Procedure.

Current SQL Output:

[image: Screenshot 1 - Current SQL Output]

Desired SQL Output:

[image: Screenshot 2 - Desired SQL Output]

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks,
Abhishek.

Comment: 1. [**Do not post images of data**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557), they are not useful. 2. Did you try to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rows+to+columns+%5Boracle%5D)? Also there's no *vice versa* actually, because you just transform rows to columns. I cannot see any column became a row, do you?

Answer (score 0):

With pivot, the desired output is easily obtained

```
select * 
from myTable
pivot (
    max (COLUMN_NAME_VALUE)
    for COLUMN_NAME
    in (
       'COL1' as COL1,'COL2' as COL2,'COL3' as COL3
   )
)
ORDER BY ROW_NAME;
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4543295103862db7474c431b7a0e4e80)

Comment: Thats not flexible enough, as the per the question the data is dynamic and there can be any number of rows/columns.